# Split date range into each day within the range with start and end date

Tags: java, sql, etl, transformation, informatica

I have a scenario where a row with a date range has to be split into multiple rows for all the days within that date range. Does anyone know how to obtain target (as attached) in this scenario in Informatica powercenter?

SOURCE

```
code        start date            end date
ADMISSION   01/01/2017 02:05:11   01/01/2017 04:20:53
TRANSFER    01/01/2017 04:20:54   01/03/2017 18:30:48
DISCHARGE   01/03/2017 18:30:49   01/03/2017 20:18:11
```

TARGET

```
code        start date            end date
ADMISSION   01/01/2017 02:05:11   01/01/2017 04:20:53
TRANSFER    01/01/2017 04:20:54   01/01/2017 11:59:59
TRANSFER    01/02/2017 00:00:00   01/02/2017 11:59:59
TRANSFER    01/03/2017 00:00:00   01/03/2017 18:30:48
DISCHARGE   01/03/2017 18:30:49   01/03/2017 20:18:11
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I added a SQL in the source qualifier that will create a new date column and add a row for each date within the start and end date. Since all new rows had start and end date time as the actual start and end time, I added an expression to adjust the dates comparing with the new date column and concatenating with 00:00:00 for start date not equal to new date and 23:59:59 for end date not equal to new date

Comment: Here’s the SQ query:
with tmp(dt) as
(
select cast('20141001' as datetime)
union all
select dt+ 1
from tmp
where dt< getdate()
)
select cast(dt as date) new_date  , A.code, A.start_date, A.end_date
from tmp, example A
where 
cast(dt as date)  >= cast(A.start_date as date) and cast(dt as date) <= cast(A.end_date as date)
option (maxrecursion 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is to have a table of dates which you join against each record (sql join in source qualifier) by virtue of the date record's day being greater than or equal to the start date's day and less than or equal to the end date's day. Then    add extra logic later in the mapping to pick the start-time from the starttime field wben the days are the same otherwise from the datetablestarttime and similar for the end time

Answer (score 0):

Please try with java transformation!
Find the difference between the start and end date,
Create the new records using rowgen in java transformation.
Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for row multiplication in PowerCenter. Hence a workaround is needed. Calculate the date differences and use it to multiply rows. The options are:

- Use Java Transformation to generate extra rows ([here's an example](http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2013/02/multiplying-rows-with-java.html))
- Create a dummy table with data like [1,2,2,3,3,3,...] and use it to join on the date difference. Keep in mind the number of rows grows fast and it's not recommended for large numbers
- Create active, noncached lookup that will return appropriate number of rows for given input. Use SQL query override to fetch required number of rows for each processed row*

*assuming you create a myNumbers table with an myNumber column type bigint and populate it once with a sequence from 1 to X, you could use the following query for lookup override: `SELECT 1 FROM myNumbers WHERE myNumber = ?in_lookup_port_name?`. Use dummy port with value of 1 as condition.